# find max value in a nested list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following script:

```
data = [['A', 4], ['B', 12], 
        ['C', 20], ['D', 38], 
        ['E', 88], ['F', 88]]
        
print(max(data, key=lambda x: x[1]))
```

I get as an output only `['E', 88]`. How could I get `['E', 88], ['F', 88]` because both have the same highest value?

Comment: `mx = max(data, key=lambda x: x[1])[1];
    mx_values = [[l, v] for l, v in data if v == mx];

    print(mx_values) # [['E', 88], ['F', 88]]`

Comment: @azro `max_values = [couple for couple in data if couple[1] == mx]` so that the result is always in the same container as the base data without having to specify that it's a list (your `[l, v]`).

Comment: @Guimoute Is azro's solution wrong?

Comment: @user977828 No it works, but if you change your `data` to contain tuples (`data = [('A', 4), (B', 12), ...]`) the value returned by azro's method will be lists instead of tuples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do:

```
data = [['A', 4], ['B', 12],
        ['C', 20], ['D', 38],
        ['E', 88], ['F', 88]]

lookup = {}

for pair in data:
    lookup.setdefault(pair[1], []).append(pair)


max_key = max(lookup)

print(lookup[max_key])
```

**Output**

```
[['E', 88], ['F', 88]]
```

The function [setdefault](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault), does the following (from the documentation):

> If key is in the dictionary, return its value. If not, insert key with
> a value of default and return default. default defaults to None.

Comment: No need to use key with max argument in my solution max(lookup) is going to be on the keys of the dictionary